# String or binary data would be truncated error with fuzzy join

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, fuzzy

I have the below query which I'm trying to bring through all objects which use a scalar value function however I get a String or binary data would be truncated error. Please assist.

```
Select 
    definition 
From
    sys.sql_modules M
Join
    (Select 
        name 
    from 
        sys.objects O
    where 
        type_desc = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION')T
on 
     '%' + T.name + '%' Like '%' + M.definition +'%'
```

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Based on metadata used in query, it's sql server

Answer (score 0):

Some of the returned record has length greater than destination column length. Increase length of your destination column. To Debug further, run below query on SQL Server. This will give you minimum length of destination column that you need in order to avoid this error.

```
Select 
    max(len(definition ))
From
    sys.sql_modules M
Join
    (Select 
        name 
    from 
        sys.objects O
    where 
        type_desc = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION')T
on 
     '%' + T.name + '%' Like '%' + M.definition +'%'
```

I noticed after comment of a user, your *pattern* is exceeding 8000 character limit since definition column is varchar(max) and must be exceeding length over 8000 characters.

```
'%' + T.name + '%' Like '%' + M.definition +'%'
```

[**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

> **pattern** - Is the specific string of characters to search for in
>   match_expression, and can include the following valid wildcard
>   characters. pattern can be a maximum of 8,000 bytes.

What you might be interested in is

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules AS M
JOIN
(
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects AS O
WHERE type_desc = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
) AS T
ON M.definition LIKE '%'+T.name+'%'
```

Comment: There is no destination column.